# Populate mapping in global scope returns error

Tags: solidity, mapping, state-variable

I'm confused about mappings. I always used them by populating them through functions.
Now I need a simple mapping with a handful of items and wanted to populate it like this:

```
mapping(uint8 => string) public myMap;
myMap[0] = "String A";
myMap[1] = "String B";
```

But I get a compiling error:

```
ParserError: Expected identifier but got '='
```

What am I doing wrong?

I tried to declare the mapping before the construct, and then populate it inside the construct, but then I'm not able to retrieve those 2 values later on in the contract. They look empty. I'm missing something :/

I'm using Solidity 0.8.22

Answer (score 2):

**You can only populate a mapping or an array in a function or in a construct, other variations not supported by Solidity.**

Hence the error that you're getting: `ParserError: Expected identifier but got '='`

Re

> I tried to declare the mapping before the construct, and then populate
> it inside the construct, but then I'm not able to retrieve those 2
> values later on in the contract. They look empty. I'm missing
> something?

Here's a working PoC piece of code demonstrating how to populate a mapping inside a constructor and then retrieve these values later in a function:

```
    // SPDX-License-Identifier:
    pragma solidity 0.8.22;
    
    contract Test {
        mapping(uint8 => string) public myMap;
    
        address private immutable owner;
    
        constructor() {
            owner = msg.sender;
    
            myMap[0] = "String A";
            myMap[1] = "String B";
        }
    
        function retrieve(uint8 index) external view returns (string memory item) {
            item = myMap[index];
        }
    }
```

[image: result]

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Mila!
I was doing good with the construct, I did like you wrote... but I was returning the wrong thing in the function retrieving the strings. Glad you insisted on that route!

Comment: Glad it helped! You can test it to see if you're still getting unexpected strings.

If there's still a problem, then the culprit might be how you access the mapping's values.